# Android need to ping url onDestroy event

Tags: android

Is there any way to ping a url on Activity onDestroy event. I have tried to use AsyncTask as some tutorial said that it will execute after onDestroy but it doesn't work.

This is the class i ping on destroy

```
public class inactive extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String res = new String();
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            URLConnection uc = null;
            try {
                URL urll = new URL(new StringBuilder()
                        .append("www.myuru.com").toString());
                uc = urll.openConnection();
                uc.connect();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                int read;
                char[] chars = new char[1024];
                while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1)
                    buffer.append(chars, 0, read);
                res = buffer.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return res;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
}
```

and this is the onDestroy method from my activity

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    new inactive(this, sharedpreferences).execute();
    super.onDestroy();

}
```

My tests have shown that this code breaks when it tries to open the connection (urll.openConnection()).

I have tried threads, async tasks and syncronously calling the url with multiple methods like: URLConnection, HttpGet

Comment: Please post the code you are using to ping the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is difficult since you have to run the network request in the background(asynchronously).

So even though you schedule the network request to happen in the background it might/probably fail since you then destroy the Activity that sent it.

A different approach might be to save the message you want to send on file(synchronously) and then fire it later when the user start the app again.

---

A more sophisticated approach might be to start a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) (can live without an Activity being present in the foreground) and let that handle any network request.

As a note, I would however avoid doing large amount of work via Services because then the user will notice degraded performance.

Comment: Thank you! I have moved my url pinging code to a service and now it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Easy approach:

```
@Override
onDestroy(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            ping();//your ping code here!

        }
    }).start();
    super.onDestroy();

}
```

Comment: I have tried something like this this inside a Thread and it didn't work.
                    HttpURLConnection urlc=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlc.setConnectTimeout(1000*30); 
                    urlc.connect();

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? Do you want to write it to a file? If yes, then I think you should check your code related to read and write url rather than checking the `AsyncTask` or `Thread`. Moreover, you didn't write anything related to sharedPreferences.

Comment: I know how to ping a url. The problem is that the app is destroyed when I try to do that. Can you post a working example please.